# How to Temporarily remove a value from Map when a user chose that value in metabase

Tags: postgresql, metabase

I want to display a map where if the user choose a state from the dropdown menu, the value chosen will be removed from the map and the rest will still be displayed (Temporary un-view it)

Below is my code

```
SELECT "Total Calls", "State Name"
from(
    select count(*) as "Total Calls",
        t.state_name as "State Name"
    from t
    where (
        created_on::date between '22-02-2019' and '01-03-2019'
        [[and{{State}}]])
    group by t.state_name
)calls 
group by "Total Calls", "State Name"
```

i'm using PostgreSQL for this query and metabase as a source for visualisation of the data.

Below attached are the map displayed for this query

[image: Original map]

Desired output is to temporary remove this value from this state, when the user choose this state, and display the rest of the value that are not chosen

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Does the selection need to be done on the actual map, or would it be ok for it to be done via a filter?